# how to set orientation of rtsp stream video in portrait in android?

Tags: android, rtsp

I am trying to play rtsp video stream in portrait orientation, Can any body help me for this?

I have done something like this 

`videoView.setVideoPath("rtsp://172.18.24.105:1234");
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();`

[Video is playing in this way,Click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODnmp.png)
Below is the activity code from which i have started rtsp stream and it can also play rtsp stream from rtsp url,the problem is rtsp video stream is playing in other direction like as in above picture link.
Can anybody help me for this? Is there any problem in my activity code that starts rtsp stream that may have affected in orientation of video stream

public class Example1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";
private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
private RtspServer mRtspServer;
private ActivityExampleBinding binding;
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private VideoView videoView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_example);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    // Sets the port of the RTSP server to 1234
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(RtspServer.KEY_PORT, String.valueOf(1234));
    editor.apply();

    SessionBuilder.getInstance()
            .setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView)
            .setPreviewOrientation(90)
            .setContext(getApplicationContext())
            .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_AAC)
            .setAudioQuality(new AudioQuality(16000, 24000))
            .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264)
            .setVideoQuality(new VideoQuality(176, 144, 12, 56000))
            .setCamera(1)
            .build();

    // Starts the RTSP server
    this.startService(new Intent(this, CustomRtspServer.class));

    binding.btView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (binding.etUrl.getText().toString().startsWith("rtsp://")) {
                prefs.edit().putString("rtspUrl", binding.etUrl.getText().toString()).apply();
                binding.video.setVideoPath(binding.etUrl.getText().toString());
                binding.video.requestFocus();
                binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                binding.video.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
                binding.video.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
                        binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                binding.video.start();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Example1Activity.this, "Please enter valid rtsp URL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    bindService(new Intent(this, CustomRtspServer.class), mRtspServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    String url = prefs.getString("rtspUrl", null);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
        binding.etUrl.setText(url);
    }
}

private ServiceConnection mRtspServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mRtspServer = (CustomRtspServer) ((RtspServer.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        mRtspServer.addCallbackListener(mRtspCallbackListener);
        mRtspServer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    }

};

private RtspServer.CallbackListener mRtspCallbackListener = new RtspServer.CallbackListener() {

    @Override
    public void onError(RtspServer server, Exception e, int error) {
        // We alert the user that the port is already used by another app.
        if (error == RtspServer.ERROR_BIND_FAILED) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(RtspServer server, int message) {

    }

};

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mRtspServer != null) mRtspServer.removeCallbackListener(mRtspCallbackListener);
    unbindService(mRtspServiceConnection);
}
```

}`

**activity_example**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:color="@android:color/background_light"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.gl.SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/etUrl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            app:backgroundTint="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Play" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what do you mean by orientation in portrait mode??

Comment: Right now my video is playing in wrong orientation, so i want it to play in portrait view

Comment: My requirement is to change orientation of video

Comment: So you mean your video is not playing in portrait mode by default?

Comment: yes it is playing in wrong orientation.

Comment: is that video link playing in correct direction? post your xml code also